# GCP - Send Alert every X on the counter - log based metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, metrics, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to setup GCP Alert for Every X minutes, regardless of the threshold or condition?

I want to create a `counter` metric that counts occurrence of specific log entry in the logs and Alert that value every X minutes.

For instance, I have a log entry something like "Request received xxxx". I want to get notified (Alert) every 30 minutes with count of requests received.

Comment: An unusual question.  If I may ask, how will you be receiving the alert?  My immediate thought is not to use Cloud Monitoring alerts but instead used Cloud Scheduler to fire off some processing every 30 minutes that performs a query or Cloud Logging retrieval between the start period and the end period.  Your compute logic now has the answer and you can then transmit that to the user via email (or other mechanism).

Comment: Does this answer you question? https://serverfault.com/questions/1057199/how-to-send-alert-on-the-same-incident-using-logs-based-metrics

Comment: @BryanL I guess that might work.

Comment: @KevinRave Thanks, let me know if you already tested the solution on the link provided and if its already working on your project.

Comment: Actually, we don't have required privileges to use Scheduler. So no use! :-).

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler is most appropriate for this behavior.

Alerts do not send data, the absence or creation of the alert based upon the condition is the data.  In this case, the condition is not relevant, and thus the alert is not meaningful.

What can be done is have the alert always trigger and the logs of the incident will have the desired count of data.